# My Discord Bot dosen't start on my Linux server

Tags: java, discord

When I try to start my Discord bot in IntelliJ it works perfectly; when I export the bot and run the jar file on my Windows computer it also works without any problem.

But when I start the bot on my Linux server the bot stops doing anything at this point:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE7Vb.png

This is the code at which point the the bot stops working all code above is just the main method.

```
this.jdaBuilder = JDABuilder.create(this.config.getObject().getString("token"), GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS, GatewayIntent.GUILD_INVITES, GatewayIntent.GUILD_VOICE_STATES);
this.jdaBuilder.setActivity(Activity.of(Activity.ActivityType.valueOf(this.config.getObject().getString("activityType")), this.config.getObject().getString("activityContent")));
this.jda = this.jdaBuilder.build().awaitReady();
```

This is the text from the image:

```
[2022-08-14 22:07:50 WARN] [JDA] You can manually disable these flags to remove this warning by using disableCache (CacheFlag .ACTIVITY, CacheFlag .EMOJI, CacheFlag . STICKER, CacheFlag.CLIENT STATUS, CacheFlag.ONLINE STATUS) on your JDABuild
```

Command to run the jar file:

```
screen -S bot java -jar bot.jar
```

Maybe someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.
My Java version was incorrect. The version hast to be 17.0.2 or higher.